# Ajax form not working (jQuery - PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

jQuery:

```
$("#contact-us-form").submit(function () {
    var nameVal = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var companyVal = $("input[name=company]").val();
    var titleVal = $("input[name=title]").val();
    var emailVal = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var phoneVal = $("input[name=phone]").val();
    var messageVal = $("input[name=message]").val();
    $.post("mailer.php", {
        name: nameVal,
        company: companyVal,
        title: titleVal,
        email: emailVal,
        phone: phoneVal,
        message: messageVal
    }, function (data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        $('#thanks').show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

mailer.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "admin@domain.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<HEREDOC
        From: $name
        Company: $company
        Title: $title 
        E-Mail: $email
        Phone: $phone \n
        Message: $message 
HEREDOC;

    echo 'success';
    mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {
    echo "failure";
}

?>
```

The data alert on the page returns `failure`, I don't understand why!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things, first the main issue is there is no `submit` variable you're passing (if there's a submit button it is *not* serialized like it would be in a normal post), so you have to add it.  Also, you can really shorten you code by using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the `<form>` here, like this:

```
$("#contact-us-form").submit(function () {
  $.post("mailer.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    $('#thanks').show();
  });
  return false;
});
```

To add your `submit` variable in there just use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and add it in, do this:

```
$("#contact-us-form").submit(function () {
  var fdata = $(this).serializeArray();
  fdata.push({ name: 'submit', value: true });
  $.post("mailer.php", fdata, function (data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    $('#thanks').show();
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: ... and what would the mailer.php look like? How do unserialize the input?

Comment: @Nimbuz - This would require no changes on the PHP side :) `.serialize()` is just a very quick way to do what you're already doing, it takes the form's elements and serializes it into `name=value&name2=value2`, etc....like you're already doing, and like a normal `<form>` POST with no JavaScript at all does.

Comment: Woohoo!! Works like a charm! Thanks a ton Nick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you're not sending a value for "submit" to mailer.php, so your condition is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data you are passing into your mail.php via JS, you have not passed in "submit" which is where you are basing your condition.

I would suggest that you pass in something like:

```
    $.post("mailer.php", { 
            name: nameVal, 
            company: companyVal, 
            title: titleVal, 
            email: emailVal, 
            phone: phoneVal, 
            message: messageVal,
action: "send-email"
        }, function (data) { 
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
            $('#thanks').show(); 
        });
```

and in your PHP change the condition to:

```
if($_POST['action'] == "send-email") {
```

Comment: Use Firebug via Firefox to track what data has been submitted behind the scenes. This will give you an idea of what is going on.