# FORM HELP - Getting PHP script to email data sent in via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post, submission

Very new to this so apologies is my question is basic but it's stumped me for some hours.

I have a contact form which uses a bit of AJAX to POST to my PHP file. The problem im having is that when i try to get the PHP to email that data to myself, it isn't reading the POST values. The PHP was working when i tested it without the JS/AJAX post method, but in order to stop the page refresh I have gone with the AJAX option. Now that i've added the ajax in, the email result isn't showing up with the data *(I can inspect and see that the Form Data is filled, just unclear why it isnt populating in the email)* :

```
Name:   
Email:   
Message:
```

Any guidance as to why my mail server only receives the text but not the POST

**Opening & Closing HTML on form:**

```
<form data-parsley-validate action="./assets/contactform.php" method="POST">
        <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="name" class="obscure">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nameInput" id="name" placeholder="Name" required data-parsley-error-message="Please enter your name"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="email" class="obscure">Email</label>
                    <input name="emailInput" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required data-parsley-error-message="Please enter a valid email address"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="message" class="obscure">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="messageInput" id="message">Message</textarea>
                </div>
<input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php
    $to      = 'hello@kymlangford.com';
    $subject = 'Post from your website';
    $message = "Name: " . $_POST['nameInput'] . "\n Email: " . $_POST['emailInput'] . "\n Message: " . $_POST['messageInput'];
    $headers = 'From: hello@kymlangford.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['emailInput'] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    exit;
?>
```

**Java for the form:**

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>         type: 'POST',
>         url: './assets/contactform.php',
>         data:  { name : $('input[name=nameInput]').val(), 
>                  email : $('input[name=emailInput]').val(),
>                 message : $('textarea[name=messageInput]').val() 
>                },
>         dataType: 'json'
> })
> event.preventDefault();
> ```
>
> });
>
> });

**--Update 08/07/2014--**

Below is the jquery code that solved my problem

```
// get the data from the form 
$('form').submit(function(event){
    var fdata = $(this).serializeArray();
    fdata.push({ name: 'submit', value: true });
    $.post('./assets/contactform.php', fdata, function (data) { 
        alert('Data Loaded:' + data); });
        console.log(fdata);
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Your problem is on you js code, especially in `data` variable. Take a look a this [Ajax form not working (jQuery - PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976290/ajax-form-not-working-jquery-php?rq=1).

Comment: Well, in javascript you have the key `name` in php `nameInput`, and so on. They have to be the same! Also, use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to debug ajax messages.

Comment: @Athafoud - Thankyou! That link was a super help. I couldn't find it when searching, as I obviously was asking the wrong questions. Thank you!

Comment: @machineaddict - Not clear what you mean on the keys matching? I've never used PHP before... but the script above worked perfectly once I updated my JS. For future reference which part of the syntax was wrong?

Comment: @user3812602: in ajax, the name you send is called `name`, in php you use `$_POST['nameInput']`, where it should be `$_POST['name']`. Got it? And `Java for the form` is actually `javascript`, they are 2 separate programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use jquery which is the same like ajax.

Here is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit').click(function(){

    $.post("sendemail.php", $("#contactform").serialize(), function(response) 
    {
       $('#message').html(response);
    });

  return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> 
<form action="" method="post" id="contactform" >
<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
<label for="email">Email:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
<label for="emailcontent">Email Content:</label><br />
<textarea name="emailcontent" id="emailcontent"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="Send Email" id="submit" /><div id="message"> </div>
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP code, save it with 'sendemail.php' filename

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailcontent = $_POST['emailcontent'];

$to = 'youremail@domain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$emailcontent = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Content: '.$emailcontent;
$headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your email was sent!";
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem was my Java, which is all fixed now.

With the PHP, is it better practice to put the information into variables first? In my version i just put the content straight in the $emailcontent. But I have seen it declared like in your example, just wondering what the advantages are of that?

Comment: For anyone interested here is the markup I needed:

// get the data from the form
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
  
  var fdata = $(this).serializeArray();
  
  fdata.push({ name: 'submit', value: true });

  $.post('./assets/contactform.php', fdata, function (data) {
   alert('Data Loaded:' + data);
  });
  
  console.log(fdata);
  event.preventDefault();

});

Comment: I'm not sure there is any advantage when doing that. However, I think it can help to make the code easy to read if I would like to add more functions to handle the content, i.e. validating variables through PHP's htmlspecialchars() function like this $emailcontent = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailcontent']);